# HTML table generated by JQuery not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

Hey been having a lot of trouble with this. A table that is being generated by jQuery is working fine in all browsers I need to support except for IE9. The table is supposed to look like

[image]

but is displaying like this in IE9

[image]

Those course terms are being rendered as one giant text instead of individual tds.

[image: IE HTML]

It is supposed to look like so:

[image]

Here is the code that is generating the table.

```
    tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tempDiv.id = "courseAvailabilityTitle";

    var availabilityLabel = $('#availabilityLabel').val();

    if(availabilityLabel != null){
        tempDiv.innerHTML = availabilityLabel;
    }
    else{
        tempDiv.innerHTML = "Course Availability";
    }
    bodyDiv.appendChild(tempDiv);

    // Course Availability Table
    tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tempDiv.id = "courseAvailability";
    html = "<table align=\"center\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" border=\"0\">";
    html += "<tr id=termAvailability>";

        for ( var i = 0; i < courseDesc.termHeaders.length; i += 1) {
            html += "<td class=\"availabilityTerms\">"
                    + courseDesc.termHeaders[i] + "</td>";
        }

    html += "</tr><tr id=\"termsRow\">";

    for ( var i = 0; i < courseDesc.availability.length; i += 1) {
        html += "<td class=\"availabilityBox\">&nbsp;</td>";
    }
```

I was thinking the problem may be in the html+=. I tried replacing this with an .append but couldn't get it to work correctly. Any help or idea's would be greatly appreciated, this has been driving crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This JSFiddle should work.](http://jsfiddle.net/5dmey0z7/2/)

Here is what I see in the dev tool (IE10, in IE9 standards mode):

[image]

I was unable to reproduce your exact problem, but I found that the `appendChild()` statement in the middle was causing some bad output for me, e.g. `"undefined"`, or `"[Object object]"`. I moved the append down to the end and it seems to work fine.

```
document.getElementById('bodyDiv').appendChild(tempDiv);
```

If that doesn't help, maybe try explicitly adding a tbody before adding rows.